# Ionic distorting images

Tags: html, css, image, ionic-framework

i am trying to display images and text side by side but when i test the app both in the browser and on my android device the images appear really narrow the first time the page is viewed and when i go back to the page the image looks correct.

`1st visit`

[image: distorted images]

`2nd visit`

[image]

Code

```
        <ion-item ng-repeat='item in clients' class="item-text-wrap">
            <h3>{{item.clientName}}</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <img ng-src="./img/{{item.clientName}}.jpg" 
                alt="{{item.clientName}}'s Screenshot" class="portfolio-img">
                <div class="">{{item.clientBio}}</div>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio-img{
    width: 120px;
    height: 214px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you including the responsive meta tags in you header?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also, look into media queries as it will give you more control on displaying on smaller resolutions such as mobile!

I've created this fiddle which might help too? 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kx2jqxgq/)

Comment: i have the following meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">` i would like to reiterate that the above screenshows are of the same screen size, without changing code. it is just distorted on the first visit.

Comment: Can i see your full code? I need to see .Row 

Maybe make a fiddle for me to have a look at?

Comment: i cant really create a fiddle as there are a lot of css classes from the framework in use. also all the content is being loaded from a json file.